# LINQ - Comparing a List of strings against a colon separated field

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to do a LINQ where clause and split a varchar field on a : into a collection and compare this to another collection to see if any values match.

For example, we have a `List<string>` called AllowedHolders which contains ARR ACC etc.. however the field in the database (**which unfortunately we cannot change**) is a varchar but has values separated by a colon: i.e. ":ARR:ACC:"

What we would like to do is write a LINQ where clause which can check if any of the AllowedHolders appear in the field. As we wish to restrict the results to only bring back records where the field contains a value in the AllowedHolders collection.

We have done the following where the field only contains a single value

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedBusinessAreas.Contains(S.SIT_BusinessArea));
```

But the following will not work because SIT_HolderNames contains values separated by a colon:

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedHolders.Contains(S.SIT_HolderName)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. If you need me to explain anything further please let me know.

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedHolders
  .Any(H => S.SIT_HolderName.Contains(H))
  );
```

or

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedHolders
  .Any(S.SIT_HolderName.Contains)
  );
```

As pointed out by the first comment, this *only* works if no holder name contains another holder name as a substring. I was implicitly assuming that all your holder names were three-letter strings like `ARR` and `ACC`. If this is not the case, consider using `(":" + H + ":")`, or find a more safe solution.

**Edit:** Just for completeness, here are two versions with colons prepended and appended:

```
// OK if some name is contained in another name as a substring
// Requires colon before the first and after the last name
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedHolders
  .Any(H => S.SIT_HolderName.Contains(":" + H + ":"))
  );
```

And:

```
// OK if some name is contained in another name as a substring
// Ugly checks included to handle cases where no colons are present in the extreme ends
searchResults = searchResults.Where(S => searchParams.AllowedHolders
  .Any(H => S.SIT_HolderName.Contains(":" + H + ":") || S.SIT_HolderName.StartsWith(H + ":") || S.SIT_HolderName.EndsWith(":" + H) || S.SIT_HolderName == H)
  );
```

Comment: Please note that while this may sometimes work, it ignores the separators. That this is OK **only if your search terms and items are constant-length**, ie. all strings were 5-character and your search term is 5-character too. In other case, with mixed-length values, you may end with false matches, ie. "ABC" will hit items: ":ABC:", ":ABCEDF" or ":ASDABCASD:", and now the query is useful only as a pre-filter to somewhat trim the intermediate results, and still you have to refilter it later properly!

Comment: Unfortunately my HolderList contains 2/3/4 character codes and there is one scenario where I have "AR" and "ARR". Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: @AndrewRayner As I hinted, it might be hacked to still work by just adding separator colons `":"`. See my edit for details.

Comment: AH yes I see your point, as it will check for ":AR:" and ":ARR:" I will give that a go too. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote about in my answer :P Just watch out for first/last elements. Ensure that all your data has **leading/trailing colons IN THE DATABASE**. W/o leading/trailing colons you may randonly be **skipping** the first/last entries in the list, i.e. `:AR:` will be not found in `AR:ABC:DEF:GHILJKL` due to the missing leading colon. And also, this approach requires you to ||'ate all the options in a hardcoded fashion. With a List-of-ids-to-be-matched against that colon-string, this is not useful, and you'll need dynamic expressions. I've included a link at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Aah, you've added the case for starts-with and ends-with! Sorry, I overlooked that. With this, it will work even without the bounding colons. However, that effectively triples the number of checks to be done [though the added 2 'begins/ends' are **much** faster then full 'contains'].. Depending on your DB setup, indexes and the length of data, a better idea **might* be to search `:AR:` against not the column itself, but againts expression `':' + column + ':'`. That way you do a strconcat+likeMid versus likeMid+likeBeg+likeEnd. Test which one performs better for your data set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intersect()`, `Any()` and `String.Split()`.

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(s => searchParams.AllowedHolders.Intersect(S.SIT_HolderName.Split(':')).Any());
```

For example:

```
":ACC:TEST::ARR:".Split(':') -> string[] { "", "ACC", "TEST", "", "ARR", "" };
```

You can notice the empty strings, if you don't want to take them into account use String.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries):

```
":ACC:TEST::ARR:".Split(new char[] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) -> string[] { "ACC", "TEST", "ARR" };
```

#### UPDATE

You will have to fetch the data before calling `String.Split()` using `ToList()`.

```
searchResults = searchResults.ToList().Where(s => searchParams.AllowedHolders.Intersect(S.SIT_HolderName.Split(':')).Any());
```

If the data in `searchResults` is too big what you can do is to fetch only a primary key and the `SIT_HolderName`.

```
var keys = searchResults.Select(s => new { Key = s.SIT_PKey, SIT_HolderName = s.SIT_HolderName })
                        .ToList()
                        .Where(s => searchParams.AllowedHolders.Intersect(s.SIT_HolderName.Split(':')).Any())
                        .Select(s => s.Key)
                        .ToList();

searchResult = searchResults.Where(s => keys.Contains(s.SIT_PKey));
```

I don't know what can be the performances of the above query. Otherwise, you can try with a `Join()`:

```
searchResult = searchResults.Join(keys, s => s.SIT_PKey, key => key, (s, key) => s);
```

Comment: Get the following exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It will work on COLLECTION, but are you sure that it will run ON THE DB with that Split()?

Comment: @Cedric the problem is this is a LINQ to Entity query and it throws an exception when I try and use the String.Split method

Comment: it is not a good suggestion to fetch ALL ROWS to perform a lookup, even if we are speaking about one-column only. btw. the question stated `As we wish to restrict the results to only bring back records where`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yes this is why I have added that it's possible only to fetch the _SIT_HolderName_ and a primary key only. But in this case, I need more information about the data in _searchResults_ (especially a key). Otherwise, I don't see any other possibility using LINQ.

Comment: There is a lot of data in searchResults including the primary key. I would prefer not to fetch the data before performing the restriction but if this is my only option I may have to do that.

Comment: @AndrewRayner What is the primary key?

Comment: @AndrewRayner I've updated my post with the solution fetching only _SIT_PKey_ and _SIT_HolderName_.

Comment: Thanks, I will give them a try.

Comment: That solution worked for me and is quite fast :) thanks for your help

Comment: Instead of `searchResults.ToList().Where(...)` maybe you can use `searchResults.AsEnumerable().Where(...)`. It should also force the last part of the query to be "LINQ-to-objects".

Comment: The 'tolist' enforces linq-to objects as it materializes the result to an IList<> instance. It is not a required behaviour, but all linq<->sql providers known to me behave that way. otherwise it'd be rather hard to implement or performing very bad, to emulate list's random-access via additional extra queries:) But, even if not probable thing to stuble upon, it is possible: such logic-heavy IList<> could be returned ie. as a kind of paging wrapper/helper. I agree that asenumerable is better here - just a streamreader, no possibly-huge temporary buffer. And one not-needed spec less in the algo!

Answer (score 0):

If in the DB column's values the separators are indeed in the format:

```
:AAA:BBB:CCC:DDD:
```

and not just (please note the first and last character!)

```
AAA:BBB:CCC:DDD
```

then you may perform a `LIKE` lookup:

```
select .... from ... where column LIKE '%:BBB:%'
```

which translates into LINQ:

```
var idWithColons = ":" + "BBB" + ":";

from ... where .... column.Contains(idWithColons)
```

for many possible IDS, you'd have to produce:

```
select .... from ... where column LIKE '%:BBB:%' OR column LIKE '%:DDD:%' OR ..
```

which translates into LINQ:

```
var idWithColons = ":" + "BBB" + ":";
var idWithColons2 = ":" + "DDD" + ":";

from ... where .... column.Contains(idWithColons) or column.Contains(idWithColons2)
```

But that's good only for small number of alternatives. For unknown list of IDs, you can try to rewrite it as a dynamically built filter, but that's not so easy if you are not familiar with `Expression<Func<>>`.. Anyways, searching via LIKE is not so good idea anyways.. but that's not many other options :/

otherwise, well, that's unpretty.. you could probably prepare a scalar-valued function on the sql server and register it somehow in your linq provider, but I dont think it's worth it..

EDIT:

building where-clause dynamically is explained ie. here http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx - look for the PredicateBuilder. The builder is actually generic and will be directly usable, but you still will have to write the small loop that concatenates OR-LIKE by yourself. I think the article is well written enough, drop me anote if you find any problems. except for the performance. LIKE %% is not fast.